# Give name to existing constraint without dropping

Tags: oracle

I'm learning ORACLE and create a table with different columns and constraint, Now I want to give a name to already created constraint without dropping the constraint. How I can give name to them? as I see there are couple of constraints in `user_constraints` table, but I don't know their name like(null, unique) and their column.

**Again I want to give name to my existing constraints(which have default oracle created name like ( SYS_C0010392 ).**

Here is query image that I used to create table with constraints.( SQLPLUS not allowing to copy the query that's why I add image )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dept RENAME CONSTRAINT SYS_C0010392 TO new_name;
```

And SQL*Plus is console application as any other so you definitely can copy selected text.

Column CDB/DBA/ALL/USER_CONSTRAINT.CONSTRAINT_TYPE describes the constraint type, see http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn20047.htm#REFRN20047.

Constraint name can be specified in CREATE TABLE command:

```
create table my_table (
    col1 number
        constraint my_table_col1_nn not null
        constraint my_table_col1_uq unique
);
```

Column constraint association is available in `CDB/DBA/ALL/USER_CONS_COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'SYS_C0010392'
```

Comment: I already mentioned I don't know `SYS_C0010392` refer to which constraint? not null? unique? or for which column? then How I can give a user_friendly name?

Comment: any other? can you give me other tool name that i can use for oracle?

Comment: Thanks for your struggle but How I can column_name of `SYS_C0010392` constraint, as I see I can get type by `Constraint_type` but how column_name?

Comment: Either right click an select "Mark" drag to make selection and press enter to copy it to clipboard or enable quick edit mode in console options, then you can drag directly.